# Somehow an error is not being picked up by try... except

Tags: python, pandas, loops, try-catch, pickle

I am using a try... except loop to deal with opening a file that is updated throughout the day. Every now and then it would throw an error "pickle data is truncated", so I introduced the loop to try at least 100 times:

```
import pandas as pd

for i in range(100):
    try:
        df = pd.read_pickle('data')
        break
    except EOFError:
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

Somehow an error was thrown in the middle of the loop though? Its a problem because it stops my entire process which runs throughout the day.

Is there a better way of trying to open the file? Its updated every few milliseconds throughout the day, and all I want to do is retry a few milliseconds later if there is a problem.

Comment: Shouldn’t the other process be writing to a new file and then renaming it over the old one?  Doing it this way allows for worse possibilities than just truncation errors.

Comment: It just saves over the old one... Sorry I'm not sure what best practices is for this, is there another way of doing it? Its receives data from an API and every time new data is received the process ends with ```df.to_pickle('data')``` so automatically overwrites.

Comment: Your edit shows the correct strategy, although the rules on Windows don’t always allow it if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way (although still not foolproof) to overwrite the existing file is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df.to_pickle('tmp')
os.remove('data')
os.rename('tmp','data')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).